# Authenticated WCF: Getting the Current Security Context

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have the following scenario:

- I have various user's data stored in my database.
- This data was entered via a web app.
- We'd like to expose this data back to the user over a web service so that they can integrate their data with their applications.
- We would also like to expose some business logic over these services. As such ***we do not want to use OData.***
- This is a multi-tenant application so I only want to expose *their* data back to them and not other users. Likewise, the business logic we expose should be relative to the authenticated user.

I would like let the user use an OASIS scheme to authenticate with the web service -- WCF already allows for this out of the box as far as I understand -- or perhaps we can issue them certificates to authenticate with. That bit hasn't really been worked out yet.

Here is a bit of pseudo-code of how I envision this would work within the service:

```
function GetUsersData(id) 
 var user := Lookup User based on Username from Auth Context
 var data := Get Data From Repository based on "user"
 return data
end function
```

For the business logic scenario I think it would look something like this:

```
function PerformBusinessLogic(someData)
 var user := Lookup User based on Username from Auth Context
 var returnValue := Perform some logic based on supplied data
 return returnValue
end function
```

**The hard bit here is getting the current username (or cert info in the cert scenario) that the user authenticated with!**

Does WCF even enable this scenario? If not would WSE3 enable this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Shouldn't really be too hard, I think:

- if your users authenticated with a Windows user credential at your WCF service, you'll be able to find their credentials under

  ```
  ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity
  ```
- if your users authenticated with a certificate, you'll find their identity (which is going to be a CertificateIdentity instead of a WindowsIdentity) under

  ```
  ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity
  ```

Given a Windows identity, you can also impersonate that caller for subsequent calls down into your business or data layers, if needed - check out the MSDN docs [Delegation and Impersonation with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx), or Google or Bing for "WCF Impersonation" should give you a truckload of valuable links on that topic.

If neither the Windows nor the certificate path work for you, WCF also enables you to create your own custom authentication scheme, in which case you'd need to write an extension for WCF, plug it in, and you'd get username/password of your calling users sent to you to validate against any kind of custom store you might have.

WCF gives you a **lot** of flexibility in many ways - I highly doubt you'll find a scenario that works in WSE3 but doesn't work equally well (or better) in WCF!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! This is the exact info I was hoping for, for some reason I guess I must have missed this in the documentation.

Comment: I'm trying to get this going as well.
I'd like to see it working on my local machine running from a test client also running on my local machine. I've set up SSL and a proper (i think) HTTPS binding config.
 I'm seeing the current context is null and the anonymous context, although not null, doesn't have the values I'd expect since the user name is an empty string.
Is there some IIS setting I need to alter?

Comment: suddenly ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity is working, no longer null, and i'm seeing the expected user name being spit out in debug lines but the VS debugger won't debug my web server saying something isn't configured properly.

Comment: What if they authenticated with Forms authentication? We have the same scenario, but our users authenticate with Forms.

Comment: @esteban araya: the `.PrimaryIdentity` should be set in that case